# Cannot delete var/cache folder magento 2

Tags: magento2, cache

Hi for some reason I cannot delete the var/cache folder. Because of it I cannot switch between production > developer mode. 
When I do get the following:

> "The directory "fullurl/var/cache/" cannot be deleted Warning!rmdir(fullurl/var/cache/): Device or resource busy

I tried commands:

```
umount /var/cache > not permitted
```

**rm -rf var/cache/ > Device or Resource busy.**

Comment: Does your user have access to said folder?

Comment: This is more of server issue than a Magento one, you likely have a process using the directory. Have you tried to `lsof +D var/cache` to find out what process this might be?

Answer (score 1):

- Run below command to remove the var/cache folder:

  rm -rf ./var/cache/*
- Also use this command to remove the pub static.

  rm -rf ./pub/static/*

After run upgrade and deployment command to re-generate that folders.

Answer (score 0):

Try above steps,

Step 1. Give "read-write(recursive)" permission specially to var folder.

Step 2. See that files in `/var/report` folder are readable

Step 3. Then apply "Delete" on the cache folder

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the cache folder being mounted in tmpfs - which is one of the recommended speed boosts for magento - you had it right to umount it - but you need to find it first, issue:

```
df -h
```

Sample cropped output:

```
none                     2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /home/magentolive/public_html/var/cache
```

then copy/paste the cache path for umount something like this:

```
# umount /home/magento/public_html/var/cache
```

most likely as root - may need to contact you sysadmin and explain.
The script should run -- ah but it's not over!
need to

```
mkdir -p /home/magento/public_html/var/cache
```

otherwise it isn't there to delete. what a cruddy script. just delete the contents of the folder!